# Multiple errors C1083 despite the correctness of path and rights

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, compiler-errors

I'm compiling opencv (master) in Windows 10 x64 with VS2017, toolset v141. VS projects are generated by cmake.

I'm having multiple errors such as:

> c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file:
>   'I:\opencv-master\opencv\3rdparty\openexr\IlmThread\IlmThreadWin32.cpp': No such file or directory
>   [I:\opencv-master\build\3rdparty\openexr\IlmImf.vcxproj]

However, I don't understand how this could happen since:

- the path is an absolute path,
- the files do exist,
- the right in read access are correct

Furthermore, in IlmImf.vcxproj the many files are referenced but only few of them are mentionned in the error. It's only the files in `ClCompile` markups.

For instance, with files in `Half`, only `half.cpp` is quoted in the C1083 error:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="I:\opencv-master\opencv\3rdparty\openexr\Half\eLut.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="I:\opencv-master\opencv\3rdparty\openexr\Half\half.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="I:\opencv-master\opencv\3rdparty\openexr\Half\halfFunction.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="I:\opencv-master\opencv\3rdparty\openexr\Half\halfLimits.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="I:\opencv-master\opencv\3rdparty\openexr\Half\toFloat.h" />
    <ClCompile Include="I:\opencv-master\opencv\3rdparty\openexr\Half\half.cpp" />
```

Here is the full vcxproj file: https://github.com/mprevot/C1083/blob/master/IlmImf.vcxproj

---

EDIT

I can open each cpp file in the project in VS2017. right click + compile (alt+F7) for individual cpp files lead to the same error. But for few of them there is **also a E1696 error**.

> Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error
>   (active)  E1696   cannot open source file
>   "I:\OPENCV-MASTER\OPENCV\3RDPARTY\OPENEXR\ILMTHREAD\ILMTHREADMUTEX.CPP"   IlmImf      0
>   Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error C1083   Cannot open source file:
>   'I:\opencv-master\opencv\3rdparty\openexr\IlmThread\IlmThreadMutex.cpp':
>   No such file or
>   directory IlmImf  I:\opencv-master\build\3rdparty\openexr\c1xx    1

Command line is:

```
/MP /GS /TP /W3 /wd"4127" /wd"4251" /wd"4324" /wd"4275" /wd"4512" /wd"4589"
/wd"4018" /wd"4099" /wd"4100" /wd"4101" /wd"4189" /wd"4245" /wd"4305"
/wd"4389" /wd"4701" /wd"4702" /wd"4706" /wd"4800" /wd"4334" /wd"4244"
/wd"4267" /wd"4456" /Gy /Zc:wchar_t
/I"I:\opencv-master\opencv\3rdparty\openexr\IlmImf"
/I"I:\opencv-master\opencv\3rdparty\openexr\Imath"
/I"I:\opencv-master\opencv\3rdparty\openexr\IlmThread"
/I"I:\opencv-master\opencv\3rdparty\openexr\Iex"
/I"I:\opencv-master\build\3rdparty\zlib"
/I"I:\opencv-master\opencv\3rdparty\zlib"
/I"I:\opencv-master\build\3rdparty\openexr"
/I"I:\opencv-master\opencv\3rdparty\openexr\Half"
/I"I:\opencv-master\build" /Gm- /O2 /Ob2
/Fd"I:\opencv-master\build\3rdparty\lib\Release\IlmImf.pdb"
/Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE"
/D "_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE" /D "_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS" /D "NDEBUG"
/D "_VARIADIC_MAX=10" /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Release\"" /D "_MBCS"
/errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /GR /Gd /Oi /MD /Fa"Release/"
/EHa /nologo /Fo"IlmImf.dir\Release\" /Fp"IlmImf.dir\Release\IlmImf.pch"
/diagnostics:classic
```

and additional option `/bigobj`

Comment: `IlmThreadWin32.c pp` is there a space between `c`, and `pp`, in your actual `vcxproj` file, or that is just a copy-paste error?

Comment: This is only a paste error. I'm correcting this immediately.

Comment: Can you open any of the files by double-clicking them in the project tree?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux "the files do exist"; the path in explorer opens the file, `Test-path file_path` returns true.

Comment: Note that the compiler does not try to open the headers mentioned in the project when you compile, so that you don't see any errors for them is as expected.

Comment: @molbdnilo Well, yes and no. **If** they are not part of precompiled headers **and** opening any `.cpp` fails, then yes, it won't open them.

Comment: @molbdnilo yes I can open the cpp files in the project opened in VS2017

Comment: @Soleil What happens when you right click any of the source files in the project tree and choose "compile"?

Comment: @MaxLanghof same message. However in the error pane, file is c1xx and line is one. Is it suspicious ? (shouldn't it be the actual line `<ClCompile Include=...` in the file vcxproj ?)

Comment: Does it work if you use the latest tagged stable release (4.0.1?) rather than the in-development master branch? Generally you wouldn't use master unless you're actually working on the OpenCV library itself.

Comment: @DanMašek That's the point, working on opencv. Actually it works with master downloaded from zip, unzipped with powershell; git clone/pull was done from WSL, but cmake was executed from powershell. This does not make sense to me. I'll give the release source a try and give a feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is happening when I `git pull/clone` with the linux version (WSL), but **not with the Windows version** (packed with Visual Studio). It might be an unprintable character or something since this was not happening with the linux `git` at the beginning of opencv-master 4.0.0.

I not sure if this should be reported in the WSL project.
Any hint is still welcome.